# Absolute value of $f_a(z) = z+a (1-z)^3$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials

I am having trouble constructing a function with the following property:
Define the function $f_a: B(0,1)\to\mathbb{C}$ by $f_a(z) = z+a(1-z)^3$, where $a>0$. Is it possible to choose $a$ such that $|f_a(z)| < 1$ for all $z$?

What I have tried so far is:

1) Let $f(z) = z$ and define $f_n(z) = z+\frac{1}{n}(1-z)^3$ and note $f_n \to f$ uniformly. This seemed to be a dead end, since this only gives $|f_n(z)-z| < \varepsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$.

2) For $a>0$ apply the fundamental theorem of algebra to $f_a$ to obtain
$$ f_a(z) = -a(z-r_1)(z-r_2)(z-r_3) $$
but I take the roots of $f_a$ depend on $a$, so I cannot begin to pick $a$ small without changing the roots.

I would very much appreciate a hint or a solution. Thanks!

Comment: $a$ must be fixed, no?

Comment: mh, I see my explanation might not be quite clear. I am looking at the class of functions $f_a(z) = z+a(1-z)^3$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and I want to show there is an $a$, such that $|f_a(z)|<1$ for all $z\in B(0,1)$.

Comment: The point is I don't know what $a$ is - I want to find an $a$ (or show that one exists) with the property that $|f_a(z)| < 1$.

Comment: As far as I know, for $|a|<\dfrac{1}{4}$ we have $f(\mathbb{D})\subset\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of a proof?

Comment: For $a = -\frac{1}{8}$, you have $f(-1) = -1 - \frac{1}{8}(2^3) = -1 -1 = -2.$ So your conjecture about $|a| < 0.25$ must be wrong. In fact, by looking at $f(-1)$, you can see that $a$ must be positive. (I'm assuming that $a$ is real here).

Comment: BTW, I suspect that the Schwarz Lemma (or its proof) might be relevant here, but this is a completely wild guess

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks for the nice suggestion! I have tried applying Schwarz Lemma to $g_a(z) = f_a(z)-a$, since this satisfies $g_a(0) = 0$, but this only gives $|f_a(z)-a| < |z|$, which is only close to being the desired. I don't really see how I can modify the proof to my needs.

Comment: But $f$ not necessarily univalent to apply Koebe theorem!

Comment: Any $a$  such that $0 < a < 1/6$ works.

Comment: @quasi Can you point me in the direction of a proof?

Comment: @Mads Friis -- I'm working on writing it up -- may take a while. If it survives the write-up, I'll post it.

Comment: @Mads Friis -- Unless I made a mistake, a futher restriction on $a$ is needed, namely $a_1 < a < 1/6$ where $a_1$ is irrational but is approximately 0.0173705485. As far as posting my solution, I may hold off, since the way I did it is very messy, and most likely,  someone else, using a more sophisticated method, will probably be able to do it with less effort.

Comment: @Mads Friis -- Yes, I made a mistake about $a_1$.  My original claim $0 < a < 1/6$ appears correct, and is further supported by Kelenner's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A second try:

By the maximum modulus theorem,  for any $z$ such that $|z|<1$, we have $|f(z)|\leq {\rm Max}_{\theta}|f(\exp(i\theta))|$  Using $1-\exp(i\theta)=-2i\sin(\theta/2)\exp(i\theta/2)$, and factorizing by $\exp(3i\theta/2)$, we get

$$|f(\exp(i\theta))|^2=|\exp(-i\theta/2)+i8a\sin(\theta)/2)^3|^2$$
and this is $1-16a(\sin(\theta/2))^4+64a^2(\sin(\theta/2))^6$.

Now put  $t=\sin(\theta/2)^2\in [0,1]$, and $g(t)=1-16at^2+64a^2t^3$;  On $[0,1]$, and for $0<a<1/6$, we have that $g$ is decreasing, and $M={\rm Max}_{\theta}|f(\exp(i\theta))|=1$. Now if for a $z\in B(0,1)$, we have $|f(z)|=M=1$, by the maximum modulus theorem, $f$ is a constant, a contradiction and we are done

Comment: Thanks, I just went through your calculations and I very much agree!