# Is $f(z)=z+\frac{1}{10}(1-z)^3$ a maps which sends the unit disk to itself?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I was currently viewing the paper [*Rigidity of Holomorphic Mappings and a New Schwarz Lemma at the Boundary*, by Daniel M. Burns and Steven G. Krantz](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1994-07-03/S0894-0347-1994-1242454-2/S0894-0347-1994-1242454-2.pdf). In this paper they prove the following statement.

Let $D$ denote the unit disc centered at $0\in\mathbb{C}$.

Let $\phi\colon D\rightarrow D$ be a holomorphic function from the disc to itself such that
$$\phi(\zeta)=1+(\zeta-1)+O\left((\zeta-1)^4\right)$$
as }
$\zeta\to1.$ Then $\phi(\zeta)\equiv\zeta$ on the disc.

They say that the exponent $4$ is strict and present a counter example of the function
$$\phi(\zeta)=\zeta-\frac{1}{10}(\zeta-1)^3$$
to be a holomorphic function from the disc to itself.

So therefore arrives my question. It is clear to me that particular $\phi$ is holomorphic on $D$ and has also the "big-O" condition with the 3-exponent. However, I cannot conclude that it maps $D$ to $D$. In the paper, they state that this is due to "simple geometric arguments". Can anyone elaborate on what they mean?

Comment: Might not be a solution depending on what exactly "self-map" means (is it $\phi(\mathbb{D}) = \mathbb{D}$ or only the inclusion $\phi(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$? You have your answer if it's the latter), but in this post, [Absolute value of $f_a(z) = z+a (1-z)^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2102872) - found using [Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cphi(z)%3Dz%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B10%7D(1-z)%5E3%24&p=3), it's proven that for $0 < a < \frac{1}{6}$, the map $f_a : z \mapsto z + a (1-z)^3$ is such that $f_a(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$.

Comment: The authors didn't talk about "self-map" but "function from the disc to itself" (I edited the post accordingly). However, the post linked by @BrunoB does not give "simple geometric agruments".